# What happens if a spliced spell leaves the stack mid-resolution?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Some spells remove themselves from the stack. For example [Glittering Wish](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Glittering%20Wish) exiles itself or [Unexpected Results](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Unexpected%20Results) sometimes returns itself to your hand.

If you splice [Everdream](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Everdream) onto such a card, what happens? Do you draw the card from Everdream even if it leaves the stack first?

According to the rules for splice:

> 702.47e. The spell loses any splice changes once it leaves the stack for any reason.

(Perhaps this is meant to ensure that splice changes wouldn't apply the next time the spell is cast, for example.)

But also:

> 608.2k. If an instant spell, sorcery spell, or ability that can legally resolve leaves the stack once it starts to resolve, it will continue to resolve fully.

Comment: There is a distinction between a spell and a card. Once a spell had started resolving, it is independent of the card it used to be on. It gets a lot of properties from the card, like colour and owner, but it is more or less entirely decoupled.

Answer (score 1):

**The spell will continue to resolve with its splice effect.**

702.47e only means to say that the modified spell does not keep the spliced text when it leaves the stack. It is a corrolary of 400.7:

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.

608.2k is not affected by this.